# Use select query to add values to a hive column

Tags: sql, hive, max, hiveql, sql-view

I am having a hive table AAA having 5 columns, say A,B,C,D,E. I want to add a column F to AAA, such that all rows of F should contain maximum value of E.
Example :

**TABLE AAA**

```
A|B|C|D|E 
__________
1|2|3|4|5
2|3|4|5|6
3|4|5|6|7
```

Add column F to AAA. Final table should have something like this.

```
A|B|C|D|E|F 
___________
1|2|3|4|5|7 
2|3|4|5|6|7 
3|4|5|6|7|7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*, max(e) over() as f
from aaa t
```

I wouldn't recommend storing this derived information, because it is hard to maintain (whenever a `e` value changes on any row, then you might need to recompute the while `f` column).

An alternative would be to create a view:

```
create view v_aaa as
select t.*, max(e) over() as f
from aaa t
```

Comment: Actually the columns in table AAA is having multiple datatypes. So it will not be possible to take the greatest. The column E is having a date field and I want max value of that date field as column F values.